# Is this transformation symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ with the inner product defined as $\langle u,v \rangle = \int_{-1}^{1}u(t)v(t)dt$

And let T be a transformation such that

$$T:V\rightarrow V$$

$$p\mapsto T[p](x) = p(-x)$$

Is T going to be symmetric?

Well, I know that for a transformation to be symmetric it has to obbey the following statement:

$$\langle T[p](x), y \rangle = \langle x, T[p](y) \rangle \quad (1)$$

or in other words

$$\langle p(-x), p(y) \rangle = \langle p(x), p(-y) \rangle$$

First problem: I don't think I understand the notation. Let's say I have a basis $B=(1,x,x^2,...)$. If I take $p(1)$ and apply the transformation will I have $T[p](1) = p(-1) = -1$? And if I take $p(x)$ and apply the transformation will I have $T[p](x) = p(-x) = -x$?

Second problem: If the above is right, what I have to do is plug different vectors and test whether or not $(1)$ applies?

Any help or guidance will be appreciated!

Comment: Use \langle and \rangle to get $\langle$ and $\rangle$ respectively.

Comment: Oh, I forgot. Done!

Comment: You cannot apply $T$ to $p(1)$. $p(1)$ is a real number, not a polynomial, and $T$ only acts on polynomials. Further, for constant polynomials $T$ is an identity on them.

Comment: For it to be symmetric, isn't it that $\langle Tp,q\rangle=\langle p,Tq\rangle$? You've got the same polynomial on each side...

Answer (score 2):

$\langle x, Ty \rangle = \int_{-1}^1 x(t) y(-t) dt  = \int_{-1}^1 x(-s) y(s) ds = \langle Tx, y \rangle  $. Hence $T^* = T

**Addendum**:

Using the substitution $s=-t$ we have
$\int_{-1}^1 x(t) y(-t) dt = \int_1^{-1} x(-s) y(s) (-1)ds = \int_{-1}^1 x(-s) y(s) ds$.

Comment: I didn't understand the second equality, why can you say that $\int_{-1}^1 x(t) y(-t) dt  = \int_{-1}^1 x(-s) y(s) ds $? Is it because when I have an odd polynomial in a symmetric integral it will be 0 and because even polynomials will be equal after the transformation applied?

Comment: @Orbitz no he's introducing a change of variables $s := -t$, and removing the negative sign by instead reversing the domain of integration.